# How make Textalk/websocket-php client to check ws connection with returned values?

Tags: phpwebsocket

I've used class Textalk/websocket-php and want to check connection from client to server. If ws server is stopped, my script does not work.

```
$client = new Client("ws://localhost:8000/");
$client->ping();
```

After last row commands are not execute. I'm deprecate all errors, but this step not helped.